# SQL calculate sum total for 2 values from different tables

Tags: sql, mariadb

Looking for a SQL statement to calculate the sum of 2 values from different tables and insert them into a column

[image: Image of Tables]

I want to add the values of Markup to the Costprice and insert the total into the SellPrice

The following works on a single table without join adding 2 values together so just need to figure out the join statement

```
UPDATE Stock SET SellPrice = CostPrice + ProdID;
```

I have tried the following which doesnt work

```
UPDATE Stock SET SellPrice = stock.CostPrice 
FROM stock 
INNER JOIN Distributor on Stock.DistributorID = Distributor.DistyID Markup;
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (UPDATE FROM is a non-standard syntax.)

Comment: Please share your simple data as text not images, so it can be easy to help you

Comment: ... and also _specify_ the expected result. (I.e. provide a [mcve].)

Comment: define "doesn't work". Do you get an error? Unexpected result? Also please tag your DBMS (this issue is about SQL and has nothing to do with PHP, I already removed that tag). See also [ask] and [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: @Jarlh I'm using MariaDB

Comment: @Jarlh Example:
1 + 2 = 3

Where 
1 = Markup
2 = CostPrice
3 = SellPrice (Total sum of Markup + CostPrice)

Comment: @ADyson I receive a syntax error when trying the update command on my example

Comment: If you get an error, you always need to tell us exactly what it says! It's a lot quicker than making us guess...and sometimes it isn't possible to guess. "doesn't work" is a meaningless description - it could refer to 100 different kinds of problem.

Comment: Also being new to SQL queries i've learnt from the examples given that i can define and abbreviate Tables in the queries e.g. Stock S :-)

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit your question instead.

Comment: don't say "doesn't work".  always tell what *does* happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working solution tested on `mysql`/`mariadb` :

```
Update Stock s
INNER JOIN Distributor d on s.DistributorID = d.DistyID
SET s.SellPrice = s.CostPrice + d.markup;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this, but as the comments suggested it really depends on the DBMS you're using. This answer assumes `MySQL`:

```
UPDATE Stock X
SET SellPrice =
    (
        SELECT S.CostPrice + D.Markup
        FROM Stock S
            INNER JOIN Distributor D on S.DistributorID = D.DistyID
        WHERE S.ProdID = X.ProdID
    )
```

This is also quite time and resource expensive if this needs running on a large number of products, as it most probably will perform the subquery once for each product row.

Another way could be to insert temporary rows in the `Stock` table by regenerating the rows with a temporary key.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

INSERT INTO Stock
( StockID, ProdID, DistributorID, DistributorSKU, BrandSKU, CostPrice, StockQty, SellPrice)
VALUES
(
    SELECT
     S.StockID
    ,(S.ProdID + 1000000)
    ,S.DistributorID
    ,S.DistributorSKU
    ,S.BrandSKU
    ,S.CostPrice
    ,S.StockQty
    ,S.CostPrice + D.Markup
    FROM Stock S
        INNER JOIN Distributor D on S.DistributorID = D.DistyID
);

DELETE FROM Stock 
WHERE ProdID < 1000000;

UPDATE Stock
SET ProdID = ProdID - 1000000;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

`1000000` is an arbitrary number which should be comfortably larger than your biggest `ProdID`. Please set it accordingly.

This way it'll be much faster but, as you can see:

- You'll need to delete the previous rows and fix the keys of the news rows. So quite a delicate operation
- The above operations must be done while turning off foreign keys checks, if there are any in place

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, i did try both but unfortunately without success. I'll bear in mind the 2nd suggestion of using a temporary table if the performance appears to be slow and come back to it if needed

Comment: I'd be afraid of duplicates from the first UPDATE's subquery. And hardcoded phony values (like 1000000) in many cases tend to be a pitfall sooner or later.

Comment: @jarlh I see no problem there, as the keys will be immediately amended in the subsequesnt queries